# Vim search and replace: moving [5:0] position in a line

Tags: vim

I have code lines like these:

```
assign o_BVALID_COMP = 'h0;

assign [79:0] ARUSER_COMP = 'h0;
```

and similar variations with single bit and bus assign signals...I want to change this to following in my vim file:

```
assign o_BVALID_COMP = 'h0;

assign ARUSER_COMP [79:0] = 'h0;
```

How can I do that??

Comment: What you mean by **similar variations**? If you don't specify, you will only get solution only applicable to what you provided.